# sql query results depend on attributes of other table

Tags: mysql, sql

Cars:

```
id name
1  Mercedes
2  Audi
```

CarAttributes:

```
id car_id attribute
1  1      fast
2  1      modern
3  1      fancy
4  1      green
5  2      fast
6  2      quiet
7  2      blue
8  2      old
```

How would the sql query look if the returns depend on the attributes of the car like following:

```
[fast OR modern] AND [fancy OR old] = would return both cars
[fast OR modern] AND [old OR blue] = would only return the audi car
```

Comment: You pretty much have the syntax so give it a go and publish the query if it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select car_id
from carattributes
group by car_id
having sum( attribute in ('fast', 'modern')) > 0 and
       sum( attribute in ('fancy', old')) > 0
```